# Match values from two tables in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

One table has policy numbers and the agent who wrote each policy. An agent's name multiple times.

Another table has just the policy numbers and I want to add the agents' names next to the numbers.

VLOOKUP doesn't work because the firs table shows the agents' names multiple times.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: As long as the policy number is the unique, it should work. If you already have a formula that is not working, please share it in the question.

Comment: Index/Match? Possibly with multiple criteria?

Comment: Are the numbers duplicate or unique in the table, same number can have multi agent?

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are unique and only the Agents are duplicates, you can use Index/Match or Vlookup.
With Index / Match:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Policy!$B$2:$B$15,MATCH(A2,Policy!$A$2:$A$15,0)),"")
```

Policy is the sheet where you have Numbers (Column A, A2:A5)and corresponding Agent (Column B, B2:B15) change the references to correspond the last row but keep $ for fixed references. You can drag it down next to A2 where the numbers that you need to find their Agent are.

With Vlookup:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Policy!$A$2:$B$15,2,FALSE),"")
```

You can drag it down, next to A2 where the numbers are in the new sheet.
Also change Policy!$A$2:$B$15 to correspond the references of your Data.
2 to return the value from the second column (Agent)
False for exact match.