# Match Identical Entries in Two Excel Tables

Tags: excel, vba

After a series of macros I am left with two tables. One of stock on System 1, and one of stock on System 2.  The lay out is as follows:

Item-Id | BatchCode | Stock

My question is: Is there any way to match up entries? i.e. If the three values match, do something (highlight, delete, hide)

My goal is to isolate the  entries where the stocks don’t match etc.
Both tables are of different sizes and probably contains something the other does not.
Another issue is that there can be multiple identical entries in each table, which breaks [Match values from two tables in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850530/match-values-from-two-tables-in-excel) Vlookup solution.

Comment: *Is there any way to match up entries?* - There are many many ways, but this site is not about writing code for you. Read [ask] and take a [tour] to learn how to receive the best help from this site. That being said, using a forth column that combines all 3 entries into one cell, and using a lookup against that is a simple solution.

Comment: My apologies, Is there a better place to ask? I don't want code written for me. I just want a general idea or method to code myself. Google and Stack are not showing up anything of this sort and none of my previous methods worked.
EDIT: Thanks for the help in your post-edit post.

Comment: Try to use formulas for this like `=COUNTIF` or `=SUMIF`. Give it a try on your own. What we at least need is a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, Sorry about not attaching an example. I have working method now that combines Scott's idea and Gravitates answer. Would you recommend I delete my question for being bad, or should I add an edit with my full solution?

Comment: I don't think it is so bad that it should be deleted. It could certainly be improved by editing it to include what you had previously tried. However, you should not edit it to include your final solution. If you wish to include your final solution (I suggest that you do), please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one off procedure, and you just need the final list of unique entries:

1. Copy all the values into a single list.
2. Highlight all three columns of data.
3. Select the "Data" tab.
4. Click "Remove Duplicates".

This will remove all the duplicates, leaving you with a list of unique values.

It will also tell you how many duplicates were removed.

[image]